# How to pass parameter to tap after a exhaustMap (or any map) operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code

```
const updatedItems$ = this.itemChangeSubject.asObservable().pipe(
    exhaustMap(itemChange => 
      this.myService.changeItemStatus(
        this.accountId,
        itemChange.item.id
      )
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => getItemsAndCache()),
        catchError(() => lastItems$.pipe(first())
        ))
    ), 
    tap({
      next: itemChange => {
        const itemStatus = itemChange.item.isItemChanged ? 'changed' : 'unchanged';
        this.clicked = false;
        this.alerts.success({
          message: `Item is now ${itemStatus}.`
        });
      }
    })
  )
```

In the `itemChange` parameter on the first `exhaustMap`, I am able to access the `item` object contained in it. However, attempting to do this in the following tap, I get an error that `Property 'item' does not exist on type 'unknown'`. How can I resolve this so I can use `itemChange` the same way I use it in the `exhaustMap`?

Comment: you can pipe the tap after the mergeMap instead of the exhaustMap, and `itemChange` will be in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `itemChange` at wrong place. In order to access it, you have to place `tap` operator at the right location in the `pipe` shown as below,

```
const updatedItems$ = this.itemChangeSubject.asObservable().pipe(
    exhaustMap(itemChange => 
      this.myService.changeItemStatus(
        this.accountId,
        itemChange.item.id
      )
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => getItemsAndCache()),
        catchError(() => lastItems$.pipe(first()),

        tap({                                 // >>>>>>>> tap at right place to access itemChange
              next: itemChange => {
              const itemStatus = itemChange.item.isItemChanged ? 'changed' : 'unchanged';
              this.clicked = false;
              this.alerts.success({
              message: `Item is now ${itemStatus}.`
        });
      }
    })
    ))
    ), 
  )
```

---

> **OR**

**Not sure above below answer**

but as per your code, you can change `itemChange` to `next` and you should be able to access it (but as said not sure about it)

instead of,

```
const itemStatus = itemChange.item.isItemChanged ? 'changed' : 'unchanged';
```

use it like,

```
const itemStatus = next.item.isItemChanged ? 'changed' : 'unchanged';
```

by keep `tap` at the same location.

Comment: The second answer did not work for me but moving the tap worked just fine!

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement ! Glad it worked for you.